Integral over variable and its complex conjugate
What I was trying to solve was an integral, where the integration variable are a complex numer $z$ and its complex conjugate $\bar{z}$. In particular the integrals are the following
\begin{equation}
\int d^2 z \; \; \left( \partial_z^2 \log \vartheta_1 \left(z\right) \right) 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\int d^2 z \; \; \left( \partial_z^2 \log \vartheta_1 \left(z\right) \right) \; \left( \bar{\partial}_\bar{z} ^2 \log \bar{\vartheta}_1 \left(\bar{z}\right) \right)
\end{equation}
with $d^2z \sim dz \; d\bar{z}$. The integrands are periodic in $z$, $\bar{z}$ and has a double pole at $z=0$, the second integral also in $\bar{z}=0$. 
What I wanted to do is to take $z=e^{it}$ and switch to a contour integral and look at the poles. However I don't undertsand how to take care of the conjugate part. Does the two variables $dz \; d\bar{z}$ become one as $dt$ ? 
These integrals are commonly used in string theory, I've always taken the result as granted. For example in Kiritsis notes https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9709062 in A.34.

(Too long for a comment)
1° The substitution $z = e^{it}$ will be of any help only in the case of a circular domain of integration.
2° All the stuff about contour intrgration with poles/residues usually works with analytic/meromorphic integrands only, but not when $\bar{z}$ is involved.
3° Ultimately, $\int\mathrm{d}^2z$ is nothing else than a surface integral on the complex plane, with respect to complex cartesian coordinates $(z,\bar{z})$. You may make a change of variables in order to work with real cartesian or even polar coordinates, with
$$
\mathrm{d}^2z = \mathrm{d}\bar{z}\mathrm{d}z = 2i\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = 2ir\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta.
$$
Obviously, the domain of integration may be parametrized differently, hence a more general change of variable $z = \varphi(s,t)$.
Nevertheless, in the end, the technique used to handle such integrals will depend heavily on the considered on the integrand and the domain of integration, so that you should clarify the context of your question.
